# ElasticSearch CrashLoopBackoff when deploying with ECK in Kubernetes OKD 4.11

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, okd

I am running Kubernetes using OKD 4.11 (running on vSphere) and have validated the basic functionality (including dyn. volume provisioning) using applications (like nginx).

I also applied

`oc adm policy add-scc-to-group anyuid system:authenticated`

to allow authenticated users to use anyuid (which seems to have been required to deploy the nginx example I was testing with).

Then I installed ECK using [this quickstart](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/cloud-on-k8s/current/k8s-deploy-eck.html) with kubectl to install the CRD and RBAC manifests. This seems to have worked.

Then I deployed the most basic ElasticSearch quickstart example with `kubectl apply -f quickstart.yaml` using this manifest:

```
  apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
  kind: Elasticsearch
  metadata:
    name: quickstart
  spec:
    version: 8.4.2
    nodeSets:
    - name: default
      count: 1
      config:
        node.store.allow_mmap: false
```

The deployment proceeds as expected, pulling image and starting container, but ends in a CrashLoopBackoff with the following error from ElasticSearch at the end of the log:

```
 "elasticsearch.cluster.name":"quickstart",
 "error.type":"java.lang.IllegalStateException",
 "error.message":"failed to obtain node locks, tried 
 [/usr/share/elasticsearch/data]; maybe these locations 
 are not writable or multiple nodes were started on the same data path?"
```

Looking into the storage, the PV and PVC are created successfully, the output of `kubectl get pv,pvc,sc -A -n my-namespace` is:

```
  NAME                                                        CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS   CLAIM                                                  STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
  persistentvolume/pvc-9d7b57db-8afd-40f7-8b3d-6334bdc07241   1Gi        RWO            Delete           Bound    my-namespace/elasticsearch-data-quickstart-es-default-0   thin                    41m

  NAMESPACE                       NAME                                                               STATUS   VOLUME                                     CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
  my-namespace                       persistentvolumeclaim/elasticsearch-data-quickstart-es-default-0   Bound    pvc-9d7b57db-8afd-40f7-8b3d-6334bdc07241   1Gi        RWO            thin           41m

  NAMESPACE   NAME                                         PROVISIONER                    RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE      ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
              storageclass.storage.k8s.io/thin (default)   kubernetes.io/vsphere-volume   Delete          Immediate              false                  19d
              storageclass.storage.k8s.io/thin-csi         csi.vsphere.vmware.com         Delete          WaitForFirstConsumer   true                   19d
```

Looking at the pod yaml, it appears that the volume is correctly attached :

```
volumes:
  - name: elasticsearch-data
    persistentVolumeClaim:
      claimName: elasticsearch-data-quickstart-es-default-0
  - name: downward-api
    downwardAPI:
      items:
        - path: labels
          fieldRef:
            apiVersion: v1
            fieldPath: metadata.labels
      defaultMode: 420
  ....
  volumeMounts:
    ...
    - name: elasticsearch-data
      mountPath: /usr/share/elasticsearch/data
```

I cannot understand why the volume would be read-only or rather why ES cannot create the lock.

I did find this [similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72654220/elasticsearch-kubernetes-crashloopbackoff), but I am not sure how to apply the UID permissions (in general I am fairly naive about the way permissions work in OKD) when when working with ECK.

Does anyone with deeper K8s / OKD or ECK/ElasticSearch knowledge have an idea how to better isolate and/or resolve this issue?

Update: I believe this has something to do with [this issue](https://github.com/elastic/cloud-on-k8s/issues/2791#issuecomment-608341041) and am researching the optionas related to OKD.

Answer (score 3):

For posterity, the ECK starts an init container that *should* take care of the `chown` on the data volume, but can only do so if it is running as root.

The resolution for me was documented here:
https://repo1.dso.mil/dsop/elastic/elasticsearch/elasticsearch/-/issues/7

The manifest now looks like this:

```
  apiVersion: elasticsearch.k8s.elastic.co/v1
  kind: Elasticsearch
  metadata:
    name: quickstart
  spec:
    version: 8.4.2
    nodeSets:
    - name: default
      count: 1
      config:
        node.store.allow_mmap: false
    # run init container as root to chown the volume to uid 1000
      podTemplate:
        spec:
          securityContext:
            runAsUser: 1000
            runAsGroup: 0
          initContainers:
          - name: elastic-internal-init-filesystem
            securityContext:
              runAsUser: 0
              runAsGroup: 0
```

And the pod starts up and can write to the volume as uid 1000.

Comment: a true lifesaver indeed...